# How do I fix Java Eclipse "Launch Error" when trying to run code?

Tags: java, eclipse

Begginer here, Im trying to print a simple "Hello World" statement but everytime I try to run the code I get a "Launch Error" pop-up. I've looked through forums and videos but can't find anything on this error message.

[image]

Comment: There is something wrong the String. Did you copy paste the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your current double quotes with these " " quotes. I hope it will work

```
System.out.println("Hello World");
```

Try replacing this above line in your workspace and if the error persists, hover on the cross icon on line number 5.

And please specify what does it say after hovering on it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I switched out my line with the one you provided however the problem still persists. When hovering over line number 5 its states "public static void main(String[] args) {
>   // TODO Auto-generated method stub"

Comment: Have tou saved your file after replacement... if yes and the error still exists then try changing 
public static void main(String Args[])
into
public static void main(String args[])

i.e change Args[] with args[]

Comment: Thanks for the help, problem sovled!

Answer (score 1):

This Solved my launch error
rightclick on java file -> select "run as" -> select "run configuration"
select "JRE" tab-> Alternate JRE -> click on installed JRE... button and select appropriate Jdk version to run
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check your configured JRE version in eclipse and try to set compilation target to 1.8 and retry.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'm not sure how to set my compilation target to 1.8. I went to project>properties>Java build path>JRE system library>edit. however, the only JRE I saw was the "JDK-17" I installed. clearly, I'm doing it wrong, would you mind explaining how to set my compilation target? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, a String has to be surrounded by regular (ASCII) quotation marks `"..."`, not by typographic quotation marks `“...”`.

Invalid:

```
“Hello World”
```

Correct:

```
"Hello World"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set compilation level from Preference-> Java Compiler as giving in below snap

[image]